# FFMPEG - process interlaced frames in mixed footage separately

Tags: ffmpeg, video, dvd, video-encoding

I have a video file - an NTSC DVD rip. I want to convert it into PAL. The problem with that NTSC DVD is that it's a mixture of 23.976 fps telecined content and true 29.97 fps interlaced content.

I would like to keep the interlaced frames, but remove the telecined frames.
I also want to process these interlaced frames separately - double rate deinterlace them, scale them up to 720x576, reinterlace them and then merge them back into the inverse telecined video.

Here is a test script I came up with that doesn't work.

```
ffmpeg -i "$in" -fflags +bitexact -flags:v +ildct+ilme -c:v prores_ks \
-c:a pcm_s16le -profile:v 2 -vendor apl0 -qscale:v 2 -qmax:v 2 \
-pix_fmt yuv422p10le \
-filter_complex "[0:v]fieldmatch=order=auto:mchroma=0:field=bottom:mode=pcn_ub:combmatch=full:\
cthresh=9:combpel=150,decimate,\
select=n=2:expr='if(eq(interlace_type,PROGRESSIVE),1,2)'[v1][v2];\
[v1]scale=size=720x576:interl=0:flags=+spline,setsar=16/15[v1];\
[v2]w3fdif=parity=tff,scale=size=720x576:interl=0:flags=+spline,setsar=16/15,tinterlace=4[v2];\
[v1][v2]concat,setfield=tff,setpts=N/25/TB[vout]"
```

I tried using the select filter to create two outputs - one with progressive frames, rest with interlaced frames. The problem is that merging them back together does not work.

Is what I'm trying to do possible with ffmpeg?